# (Python) Filling a dictionary with specific elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am kind of lost here and can't really find a similar question. Maybe also because I don't know how to search for it.

I want to import the names.csv file, which holds a bunch of names in the structure: ID, Name, Gender, Year, State, Count

Now I'm trying to transcribe all the names and `count` integers into a dictionary which I call `names`. I don't understand why it now continually returns me an empty dictionary.

Through the conditionals, I'm trying to say that IF the name is in the dictionary already, it is supposed to sum the count onto the existing count.

Can anyone help? Sadly I'm really a newbie and can't help myself...

```
with open("../data/names.csv") as file:
names = {}

for lines in file:
    data = lines.strip().split(",")
    name = data[1]
    count = data[5]
    if name == "Name":
        continue
    for name, count in names.items():
        if name in names:
            names[name] = names[name] + count
        else:
            names[name] = count

print(names)
```

Comment: What's the inner for loop supposed to do?(this one:`for name, count in names.items():`)

Comment: I am trying to define key and value of the dic..

Comment: you have two different variables called `name`: one holds the name from the csv, the other is declared in the inner for loop. the second one is hiding the first one.

Comment: Oh okay. How can I carry the first name + count vars simply into the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should avoid parsing the CSV file yourself, it can become quite tricky when e.g. quotes are involved. There is [a csv module built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

For your case, I would use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). The `.groupby()` function together with `.sum()` will do exactly what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('names.csv')
print(df[['Name', 'Count']].groupby('Name').sum())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip! I'll look into panda!

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `defaultdict` from standard python lib ([for details link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict)) and for working with csv files csv module ([link for details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader))

```
from collections import defaultdict

food_list = 'spam spam spam spam spam spam eggs spam'.split()
food_count = defaultdict(int) # default value of int is 0
for food in food_list:
    food_count[food] += 1 # increment element's value by 1

food_count
```

in result you will have:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'eggs': 1, 'spam': 7})
```